# Fixing font difference

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-webfonts

I am using this font: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins (Google Fonts). I implement it into my HTML document like this in the `<head>` tag: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
To my text I apply it with this little CSS Code:

```
* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
     appearance: none;
}
```

Everything works in Chrome. It looks like this in Chrome Version 74.0.3729.157:
[image: chrome_feeling]
And here is the style of another browser like microsoft edge Version 17.17134: [image: microsoft_edge_feeling]
As you can see there is a big difference. And to design beautiful webpages i need to fix that. Hope someone can help me out of this. Thanks. :)
NOTE: It looks like it still works normally for `<p>` elements in other browsers too. But not for `<h1>` elements. The font is normally applied on the `<h1>` element, but for some reason, I think it renders different. How to fix this?
~filip

**EDIT:**
To easily see and test my problem open this jsfiddle in different browsers (like chrome and edge): https://jsfiddle.net/filipdg/q1mhcvau/4/

Comment: Have you tried to clear your cache? Usually this can be fixed with CTRL+F5

Comment: @SuperDJ Yes, already tried. Does not work.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem include `WOFF` format in your `@font-face` declaration. Most of the modern browser supports `WOFF`

For maximum browser support include all possible format.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins';
    src: url('Poppins.eot');
    src: url('Poppins.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('Poppins.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Poppins.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('Poppins.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('Poppins.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: @Alex G. Is there a way to get the fonts online from google fonts, or must I download it and save it into my public?

Comment: Try using this instead and see if it works:

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap');
</style>

Comment: And this : body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Yes it's possible